# the height that i got from the browser i want to apply it to every class

Tags: javascript, html

so like i want each div to have a height of the browser... i did it but only using `.getelementby` but when i try to use `.getelementsbyclassnames` it does not work because according to that it brings back array of class , so i tried giving index which only works with one index... here `enter code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var height = getViewportHeight();
    var strl = document.getElementsByClassName("full") [0],[1];



    if(height > 0)
      strl.style.height = height + "px";
  }

  function getViewportHeight() {
    var h = 0;

    if(self.innerHeight)
      h = window.innerHeight;
    else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
      h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    else if(document.body) 
      h = document.body.clientHeight;

    return h;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You could this a lot easier with jQuery

Comment: So you need help looping through your array of classes?

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript:
Note: My prev solution did not work because I was using `for each`. I learnt that `for each` works only for arrays and not for Node List. getElementsByClassName returns an NodeList hence you can't use foreach loop

```
    var height = 10;
    var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('full');
    for (var i=0;i<tests.length;i++){
        tests[i].style.height = height+"px";
    }
```

Using Jquery:

```
 var height = getViewportHeight();
 $(".full").css("height",height+"px");
```

Comment: @hemath yo man.. its still not working o should i just use jquery... but am afraid j will take a lot of time doing that since i want it to be the first thing to be done before anything else

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/chace/5UXqV/29/

The first part is in jQuery so you'll need to include the jQuery library in your header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = getViewportHeight();
    console.log(height);
    $("div.full").each(function () {
        $(this).height(height);
    })
});
```